# Scipy Minimize Not Working

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimize

I'm running the minimization below:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

### objective function ###
def Rlzd_Vol1(w1, S):
    L = len(S) - 1
    m = len(S[0])

    # Compute log returns, size (L, m)
    LR = np.array([np.diff(np.log(S[:,j])) for j in xrange(m)]).T

    # Compute weighted returns
    w = np.array([w1, 1.0 - w1])
    R = np.array([np.sum(w*LR[i,:]) for i in xrange(L)])  # size L

    # Compute Realized Vol.
    vol = np.std(R) * math.sqrt(260)

    return vol

# stock prices
S = np.exp(np.random.normal(size=(50,2)))

### optimization ###
obj_fun = lambda w1: Rlzd_Vol1(w1, S)
w1_0 = 0.1

res = minimize(obj_fun, w1_0)
print res


### Plot objective function ###
fig_obj = plt.figure()
ax_obj = fig_obj.add_subplot(111)
n = 100
w1 = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n)
y_obj = np.zeros(n)
for i in xrange(n):
    y_obj[i] = obj_fun(w1[i])
ax_obj.plot(w1, y_obj)
plt.show()
```

The objective function shows an obvious minimum (it's quadratic):

[image: objective function]

But the minimization output tells me the minimum is at 0.1, the initial point:

[image: minimization output]

I cannot figure out what's going wrong.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

`w1` is passed in as a (single entry) vector and not as scalar from the `minimize` routine. Try what happens if you define `w1 = np.array([0.2])` and then calculate `w = np.array([w1, 1.0 - w1])`. You'll see you get a 2x1 matrix instead of a 2 entry vector.

To make your objective function able to handle w1 being an array you can simply put in an explicit conversion to float `w1 = float(w1)` as the first line of `Rlzd_Vol1`. Doing so I obtain the correct minimum.

Note that you might want to use `scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar` instead especially if you can bracket where you minimum will be.

Comment: Hi, I have a similar issue, can you help?